# Can I have a multicolor radio button in nextjs?

Tags: colors, radio-button, next.js

I'd like to make a radio button that determines the severity of an error, being: low, medium, high and critical, with each one having a color according to its severity (i.e. from low to critical: lime, yellow, orange & red) I only found ways in which I can customize all radio buttons, but not each one separately. Also, Nextjs' 'pure selector' restriction makes it more difficult to come up with a solution

Comment: Why can't you create a *css* class like this: `.low { color: lime }`?

Comment: The radio color cannot be directly modified like you suggested, one can alternatively use display: none and create a custom circle to be displayed as a radio, and I've managed to do this following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZq5zFSpUlo, however I haven't been able to make them to be different colors for each radio

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the tutorial you linked, this sets the color of the radio button:

```
.custom-radio-btn .checkmark {
  --check-color: #ff5722; 
}
```

So all you would have to do to modify the color is create selectors of similar specificity after that one like this:

```
.custom-radio-btn .low {
    --check-color: lime;
}

.custom-radio-btn .medium {
    --check-color: yellow;
}

.custom-radio-btn .high {
    --check-color: orange;
}
```

And conditionally apply the appropriate class to the element like this for example:

```
  <label class="custom-radio-btn left">
    <span class="label">Medium</span>
    <input type="radio" name="sample" />
    <span
      class={`checkmark ${
        error && error.severity == "low"
          ? "low"
          : error.severity == "medium"
          ? "medium"
          : "high"
      }`}
    ></span>
  </label>
```

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/XWMPXRY).